# libusb and poll / select

Tags: linux, usb, libusb-1.0

I'm using a linux OS and was wondering if there were any file descriptors I could poll/select which would trigger when data was waiting to be read from a usb device. I am also using the libusb library and have yet to find file descriptors which I can use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [libusb's polling functions](http://libusb.sourceforge.net/api-1.0/group__poll.html) to hook its file descriptors into your event loop. `select` will wake up whenever there's activity that libusb will need to handle, which includes but probably is not limited to data being available for reading.

Comment: Those file descriptors are purely for handling libusb related events, and not triggered by actual usb events.

Comment: @user2365072: That's right, but you can use them to combine your event loops. If you control the event loop, you know when your callbacks are going to be called.

Comment: Sorry, could you explain that a little further? I have experimented with polling those file descriptors and sending data to the device which I know will return messages yet the descriptors never get triggered.

Comment: @user2365072: I'm afraid I've never actually used libusb myself, so I'm just guessing, but I'd guess that you added the message to its outgoing queue but never called `libusb_handle_events` so it never got sent, and thus no reply was ever generated?

Comment: Oh ok. Well I actually have a thread which continually calls libusb_handle_events rather than integrating it into every procedure.

Answer (score 0):

No, USB devices are not always "stream" devices, so reading from a file descriptor doesn't always make sense. However, if your USB device provides a serial port driver, you can listen for incoming data on the serial port device (just like any other serial port handled by your OS).

Comment: Ok, does that also apply with HID devices which will flag before it sends that data wants to be sent?