# Integrate pyusb device into poll() loop

Tags: python-2.7, pyusb

I'm using `pyusb-1.0.0b2`. I'm converting some multi-threaded code to instead use a `select.poll()` loop, as below:

```
p = select.poll()
p.register(...)

while True:
    for fd,evt in p.poll():
       ...
```

There is code which currently runs in its own thread that primarily just calls `read()` on a pyusb `usb.core.Device` object. I want to integrate this device into the `poll` loop, but unfortunately, it doesn't expose a `fileno()` (and indeed, looking in `/proc/[pid]/fd/` there is no file descriptor open for the device.)

I see that libusb supposedly supports this: [libusb and poll / select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16765429/)

How can I implement this with pyusb?